# Is Mallow toxic to livestock or is it only Parviflora that is?

Tags: toxicology

Thank you for your time.  I have a question about toxic plants.

Mallow plants.  Specifically, my horse (while up in North Central Arizona for the Summer) had access to (and ate, unsure how much), Malva Neglecta (identified in a fb plant identification group from photos).  I have found plenty of evidence of Malva Parviflora being toxic to livestock, depending on quantity consumed. There is a write up about several horses in Australia that died from ingestion and others got rapid onset laminitis.  Link: [https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27341541/#:~:text=Reason%20for%20performing%20the%20study,euthanasia%20after%20ingesting%20the%20plant](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27341541/#:%7E:text=Reason%20for%20performing%20the%20study,euthanasia%20after%20ingesting%20the%20plant).

Should I assume both plants are toxic since they are from the same family, or is it possible only the parviflora is toxic and the malva benign?

The reason for my question, is that my horse has developed some hoof soreness issues over the Summer, and I am wondering if the mallow plants could have been an additional factor, along with too much toe sole being removed when trimmed, a very rocky pen, and a particularly wet monsoon season this year.

I posted in a vet group, but got no answer.  I think many of them just don't know.

Comment: According to [Livestock Poisoning plants of Oregon](https://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/concern/parent/1v53jx45c/file_sets/6q182k80n) (1969!) it "should be regarded with suspicion".  To quote: "Another species of cheeseweed or mallow occurring in our area is Malva neglecta Wallr. (Fig. 57), and it, too, should be regarded with suspicion". But, I suppose, that in itself is not very informative.